# Show that the modulus of a complex number is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

For a function $\|\cdot\|$ to be a norm, it must satisfy the following: Let $X$ be a vector space over the field $F$. For any $x, y\in X$ and $r\in F$

N1) $\|x\|\geqslant 0$

N2) $\|x\|=0 \rightarrow x=0$

N3) $\|rx\|= |r|\cdot ||x||$

N4) $\|x+y\|\leqslant \|x\| +\|y\|$

We let $X$ and $F$ in this case to be the set complex numbers $\mathbb C$

I managed N1) to N3) but N4) the triangular inequality just doesn't seem to work for modulus of a complex number, how can I show this?

Comment: $N1$ as stated is incorrect. It should be $\|x\| \ge 0$. $N4$ is also incorrect, it should be $\|x+y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$.

Comment: Hint: Use $|x_1+x_2|^2 = (x_1+x_2)\overline{(x_1+x_2)}$ and $Re(x_1\overline{x_2}) \leq |x_1x_2|$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836349/triangle-inequality-for-complex-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Let $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, $z=a+ib$, $w=c+id$.
\begin{align}
&|z|+|w|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2},\\
&|z+w|=\sqrt{(a+c)^2+(d+b)^2}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
|z+w|\le|z|+|w|&\iff|z+w|^2\le(|z|+|w|)^2\\
&\iff(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2\le a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}\\
&\iff ac+bd\le\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}\\
&\iff (ac+bd)^2\le(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\\
&\iff 2acbd\le(ad)^2+(bc)^2\\
&\iff 0\le(ad-bc)^2
\end{align}
which is always true.